# Angular ng-repeat - limit results to timeframe

Tags: angularjs

I have the following Model and would like to display the top voted over the last 24 hours

```
    {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "56abe20fabd3fa64187b5d21"
    },
    "user": {
        "$oid": "56a1832a36dc3d0e00c7aa3f"
    },
    "title": "Intel Pentium i5 Quad-Core i5-6400",
    "created": {
        "$date": "2016-01-29T22:05:03.574Z"
    },
    "votes": 1
}
```

So basically limiting the ng-repeat to the created field within the last 24 hours.

Filter

```
angular.module('savings').filter('lessThan', function () {
    return function(savings, requirement) {
        var filterKey = Object.keys(requirement)[0];
        var filterVal = requirement[filterKey];



        var filtered = [];


        if(filterVal !== undefined && filterVal !== ''){
            angular.forEach(savings, function(saving) {
                var today = new Date();

                var date = new Date(saving.created.$date);

                var diff = today - date;

                diff = diff / (1000*60*60);

                if(diff < filterVal) {
                    filtered.push(saving);
                }
            });
            alert(filtered.length);
            return filtered;



}

    return savings;

};
```

});

Ive tried implement the answer below but it doesnt return any results.

Screenshot of resource.

[image]

Comment: What are you having issues with in doing this? A filter on ngRepeat should do this easy enough.

Comment: I didnt realize their was a filter that could limit in that way. What filter do i need to add?

Comment: I mean a custom filter. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters

Comment: Ill take a look into that. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you start building a filter and are having issues with it, please update your question with that code so we can help in fixing it.

Comment: Ive added my attempt. It doesn't return any results. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll save you some time.. here is your filter.

```
app.filter('lessThan', function () {
 return function(items, requirement) { 
  var filterKey = Object.keys(requirement)[0];
  var filterVal = requirement[filterKey];    

  var filtered = [];    

  if(filterVal !== undefined && filterVal !== ''){      
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      var today = new Date();
      var date = new Date(item.created)
      var diff = today - date;
      diff = diff / (1000*60*60)

      if(diff < filterVal) {
        filtered.push(item);
      }
    });
    return filtered; 
  }        

  return items;
  };
 });
```

And call it like:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | lessThan: {'created':24}">
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/a2AUz9fOfVRv6YTS77PQ) is a plunker.

EDIT: Based on the screenshot created property looks more like this:

```
"created": "2016-01-29T22:05:03.574Z"
```

I've edited the filter for this model

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt seem to return any results when i try use it. Im using Mean.js. Am i right in saying i go to the controller and add the filter? the first line will be  'angular.module('savings').filter('lessThan', function () {' and then use the ' <div ng-repeat="saving in savings |  orderBy: '-votesreal' | limitTo:6 | lessThan: {'created.$date':24}>"' in the view? would this be my controller code? http://pastebin.com/LCQSKdTX

Comment: You can add console.log in the filter to see what is going on. Can you make a plunker instead of pastbin so we can help more? Also, how can you be orderingBy votesreal.. I don't see that in your model?

Comment: Sorry i removed the votesreal just to simplfy. Its there alright. The problem seems to be here 'var date = new Date(saving.created.$date);' its saying unresolved variable $date and an alert is saying 'invalid date' if i alert the date variable. Im not sure how to use Meanjs with plunker.

Comment: Ok so it works if i declare the array at the top of the controller but i want it filter the database query.

Comment: I'm guessing that your DB call is `$scope.spotlightSort = Savings.votesreal;`.. if so your html should look like `<div ng-repeat="item in spotlightSort | lessThan: {'created.$date':24}">`.

Comment: Where would the DB call be? If its not in the code i put in pastebin i dont have it. All i have is that and 'ng-repeat="saving in savings' in the view. I assume the problem is where the "$scope.savings" is not being declared. Should i be declaring it somehow at the top of the controller.

Comment: Well the good news is that you have figured out the answer to this question. Now you need to open a new question asking how to query the database in angular.  I can help you with that but for stackoverflow correctness it should be under a new question.

Comment: But surely its being queried already if it returns all the results without the filter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102049/discussion-between-brian-baker-and-chrism).

Comment: Excellent. Its 330AM here and i feel like a zombie but we got there in the end. Really appreciate it. Thanks.